# how to convert "std::chrono::system_clock::now()" to double

Tags: c++11, double, c++-chrono

```
auto current_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

Using `std::chrono` in `C++` I get current time like above.
**How can I use it to get the number of seconds since the clock's epoch as a  `double`?**

Comment: `double` meaning what? Seconds since some particular epoch? Milliseconds? Fortnights?

Comment: What use is a time value as a double? Are you sure you don't want a duration?

Comment: aah. seconds since epoch or something is what I should look at. @FredLarson got your point

Comment: Maybe look at the example here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch

Comment: its actually a bad idea to convert time to IEEE 754 binary format (binary64 in your case).. as time progresses,  actual progress steps are increased, because for very large or very small values there are bigger quants and many values become unrepresentable by float\double. Floating point represents numbers as a integer value divided by power of two.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Or, simply put, the larger the number of whole seconds, the poorer the resolution of fractional seconds. I prefer to represent store time as a 64-bit integer and a double. The integer has the number of whole seconds and the double stores the fractional second (values between 0.0 and 1.0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`time_since_epoch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point/time_since_epoch) can give you a duration since the clock's epoch (whatever the epoch may be):

```
auto current_time = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
auto duration_in_seconds = std::chrono::duration<double>(current_time.time_since_epoch());

double num_seconds = duration_in_seconds.count();
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qe1MNGQAR5X3zJl8)